# Can I add an outlet using 14AWG wiring from 20AWG wiring?

Tags: wiring

Can I add an outlet using 14AWG from the Gas Fire Place switch of 20AWG wiring?

Comment: There isn't 120V at most fireplace switches to begin with.  Why are you trying to extend from here and not from a place where you *know* you can find 120V, like another outlet?

Comment: Instead of stating the short question twice, could you elaborate on what you mean? I am particularly interested in this "20 AWG wiring". Do you mean that, or do you mean something else perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

No, 20 AWG appliance wiring cannot be extended to a receptacle unless the installation instructions allow a specific receptacle for a special dedicated purpose.

It is likely the switch doesn't have a neutral anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to any other specific rules relating to the type of device, any standard (US 15 Amp) receptacle must have wiring of at least 14AWG from the breaker all the way to the receptacle. You can use larger (e.g., mix 12AWG and 14AWG) but you can't use smaller for any piece of the hardwired circuit. Cords for appliances plugged in to a 15A receptacle may be smaller because they are based on the expected load of that specific device. But a 15A receptacle has to be able to support any standard 15A load, including a 1500W toaster or space heater.